# sql SUM result filter (dont want null or 0)

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sum

I want to `CASE STHAR_GCKOD when 'G' THEN STHAR_GCMIK >=1`
So I don't want null or 0
Is this possible ? Thank you..

```
SELECT
   STOK_KODU,
   SUM(CASE STHAR_GCKOD WHEN 'G' THEN STHAR_GCMIK ELSE 0 END) // INCOMING,
   SUM(CASE STHAR_GCKOD WHEN 'C' THEN STHAR_GCMIK ELSE 0 END) // OUTGOING,
   SUM(CASE STHAR_GCKOD WHEN 'G' THEN STHAR_GCMIK ELSE -STHAR_GCMIK END) // TOTAL
FROM 
   STOKCEK
GROUP BY 
   STOK_KODU
```

Comment: `'G' is null` how can `'G'` be null? there is already value.

Comment: i can't understand what you mean. Can you gice sample records with desired result?

Comment: 'G' is a marker, if this value matches. the minus process from does not matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `having`, which is a `where` applied after instead of before `group by`:

```
Select STOK_KODU,
sum(CASE STHAR_GCKOD WHEN 'G' THEN STHAR_GCMIK ELSE -STHAR_GCMIK end) 
FROM STOKCEK
GROUP BY STOK_KODU
having sum(CASE STHAR_GCKOD WHEN 'G' THEN STHAR_GCMIK ELSE -STHAR_GCMIK end) > 0
```